# What is the difference between start a topic branch and create a topic branch?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I was reading the [docs](https://source.android.com/source/developing) of AOSP and find this difference of describing `repo start` and `git branch` and I was confusing about what's the difference between them.

Could anyone explain this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at `repo start BRANCH_NAME PROJECT_NAME`.

I think you know the manifest used by `repo`. It has hundreds of lines like this:

`<project name="ard_5.1/android_packages_apps_Browser" path="packages/apps/Browser"/>`

`ard_5.1/android_packages_apps_Browser` is a `PROJECT_NAME` and `packages/apps/Browser` is the relative path to the code's root directory.

`repo start feature_003 ard_5.1/android_packages_apps_Browser` after `repo sync` is nearly equivalent to:

```
cd packages/apps/Browser
git branch feature_003
#or
git branch feature_003 HEAD
```

It creates a new branch `feature_003` from `HEAD` in the repository `packages/apps/Browser`.

`repo start feature_003 project1 project2` creates a new branch in `project1` and `project2`.

`repo start feature_003 --all` creates a new branch in all repositories. It's evquivalent to `repo forall -c 'git branch feature_003'`.

Now let's look at `git branch`. It's much more complicated than `repo start`. You can run `git branch --help` to learn more.

`git branch` lists all the local branches.

`git branch new_branch commit-ish` creates a `new_branch` from the revision `commit-ish`.